# Unable to cast System.Collections.Hashtable into type System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary

Tags: vb.net, logging, casting, exception, enterprise-library-5

I am using Enterprise library 5.0, in fact, logging block. In some circumstances I handle below exception if connection with remote end point is not successfull:

```
Public Function Connect(ByVal sender As Socket) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer

    result = -1

    Try
        ' Connect the socket to the remote endpoint.
        sender.Connect(remoteEP)

        Logger.Write("Socket connected to remote endpoint {0}", _
                     sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())

        result = 0

    Catch ... another exception
    Catch ... another exception

    Catch ex As System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
        Using New Tracer(Common.LOGGING_SOCKETCONNECTIONERROR)
            Dim contextInfo As IDictionary = New Hashtable()
            contextInfo.Add("Additional Info (Stack Trace)", ex.StackTrace)

            Dim provider As DebugInformationProvider = New DebugInformationProvider()
            provider.PopulateDictionary(contextInfo)

            Dim logEntry As LogEntry = New LogEntry()
            logEntry.Categories.Add(Common.LOGGING_CRITICAL_ERRORS_CATEGORY)
            logEntry.Message = String.Format("An error occurred when attempting to access the socket: {0}", ex.Message)
            logEntry.ExtendedProperties = contextInfo

            Logger.Write(logEntry)
        End Using

  End Try

  Return result
End Function
```

When above exception is fired I get a conversion error in line:

```
provider.PopulateDictionary(contextInfo)
```

The conversion error is the following:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message="Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your function PopulateDictionary expecting IDictionary or IDictionary(of TKey, TValue)? It should expect IDictionary I believe

Comment: well, PopulateDictionary has the following signature: Public Sub PopulateDictionary(ByVal dict As System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary(Of String, Object))

Comment: and contextInfo is a Hashtable, implementing System.Collection.IDictionary... So change your function's signature and everything should work OK...

Comment: @Martin  Do you mean to change PopulateDictionary signature? as far as I know it is not possible, this is the only possible signature.

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
Dim contextInfo As IDictionary = New Hashtable()
```

by:

```
Dim contextInfo As IDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, if you can't change the function's signature, change the parameters you are passing it...